# If $E\subset F$ then $\inf E\ge\inf F$ and $\sup E\le\sup F$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose

$\emptyset\neq E\subset F \subset \mathbb R$

Prove that $\inf E \ge \inf F$ and $\sup E \le \sup F$.

The second part I kind of understand. If $E$ is a subset of $F$ and $\sup F$ is an upper bound for $F$ then $\sup F$ is going to be an upper bound for $E$.

Therefore $\sup E \le \sup F$

But the infinitum part I am not sure how to show.

Comment: The words are "infimum" and "supremum," not "infinitum" and "suprenum."

Comment: "But the infinitum part I am not sure how to show." Well... *If E is a subset of F and inf F is a lower bound for F then inf F is going to be*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infimum of $F$ is the greatest element of $\mathbb{R}$ that is less or equal to all elements of $F$ so, since $E \subset F$ is also less or equal to all elements of $E$. If there are no elements in $F$ less than all elements of $E$ than it is also the infimum of $E$, else it is less than  inf$(E)$.